# Do multiple, related Python projects need their own virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have two, related Python projects:

```
../src/project_a
../src/project_a/requirements.txt
../src/project_a/project_a.py

../src/project_b
../src/project_b/requirements.txt
../src/project_b/project_b.py
```

Both projects use the same version of Python. The respective `requirements.txt` files are similar but not identical.

Do I create a separate virtual environment for each project or can I create a "global" virtual environment at the `../src` level? 
**Note**: I'm obviously new to using virtual environments.

Comment: Imo, you should have separate since you want to be developing as close to what you'll be using in production as possible

Comment: Virtual environments are usually created so that no dependency issues arise, or can be easily fixed if they do. I'd say if you're using the same libraries in both, it's not necessary

Comment: @JackHanson My apologies but I'm a little confused by "it's not necessary". Do you mean the venv isn't necessary in general? Wouldn't I create at least one so that I can be 100% certain that I'm using the expected Python version? TIA

Comment: @RobertJoseph fair, I could've been clearer. I meant I don't believe having a SECOND one is necessary. But this is my opinion, and SO is more about specific coding questions rather than opinions so I'm not going to say too much more

Comment: I feel that. And I didn't see your reputation score/badges, you already know how this works lol. Good luck with the project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtual environments are meant to keep things isolated from each other.

- If one project is a dependency of the other one, then they have to be installed in the same environment.
- If two projects have dependencies that conflict with each other, then they have to be installed in different environments.
- If two projects are meant to be run on different versions of the Python interpreter, then they have to be installed in different environments.

That's basically the rules (I can think of). And then the rest is a mix of best practices, personal opinions, common sense, technical limitations, and so on.

One could think of the pet vs cattle analogy for example. Virtual environments can be seen as throw away things, that are created on demand (automatically with tools such as [tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) for example), which is easy once the dependencies are clearly written down (in a [*pip*-style `requirements.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) for example).

In your case, I would probably start with a single Python virtual environment, and only start creating more when the need arises. Most likely this will happen once the projects grow in size. And eventually it could become an absolute necessity once a project requires specific versions of dependencies that conflict with the dependencies of the other.